# Function signature with only type as input (no variable)

Tags: go, struct, interface, go-gorm

I saw this in an open source project (interface definition). What does the notation for the function `RelationshipFKName(Relationship) string` with the single parameter `Relationship` signify here?:

```
// Namer namer interface
type Namer interface {
    TableName(table string) string
    ColumnName(table, column string) string
    JoinTableName(joinTable string) string
    RelationshipFKName(Relationship) string
    CheckerName(table, column string) string
    IndexName(table, column string) string
}
```

I would have thought it would be something like `RelationshipFKName(rel Relationship) string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For interface declarations parameter names are not mandatory they are there for readability.  In the case of `RelationshipFKName(Relationship) string` the parameter type itself make the intend clear and that is most likely the reason the author chose to not to name it. Whereas in the case for `TableName(string) string` the intend will not be clear and the author , correctly, named the parameter `table`  to make it `TableName(table string) string`